# calendar events not displayed

Tags: android, calendar

I need to add a recurring event in default android calendar and modify it if user wishes to do so. I need to do this directly i.e., without opening calendar intent. I have used the following code. The toast displays an event id for the last added event, but the event is not displayed in the phone calendar . Really troubled, but couldn't solve the issue.. Please help..

```
 public void createEvent(String title, String location, String description){

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1"));
     Date dt = null;
     Date dt1 = null;
     String Stime="2013-11-13 07:30";
     String Etime="2013-11-13 08:00";
     try {
      dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(Stime);
      dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(Etime);

      Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTime(dt);

      // beginTime.set(2013, 7, 25, 7, 30);
      beginTime.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
      cal.get(Calendar.DATE), cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
      cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

      Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTime(dt1);

      // endTime.set(2013, 7, 25, 14, 30);
      // endTime.set(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute);
      endTime.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
      cal.get(Calendar.DATE), cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
      cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

      ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

      values.put(Events.DTSTART, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
      values.put(Events.DTEND, endTime.getTimeInMillis());
      values.put(Events.TITLE, title);
      values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
      values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3 );
      // values.put(Events._ID, meeting_id);
      values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

      Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
      long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        Toast toast =Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Calender Event Added" + eventID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

     } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Also I have to use the same thing in android version less than 14. What should I update the code with ??
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code, that finally displayed the events in the default phone calendar, but still want to know if I have to use this code in >14 Version.. What should I update ??

```
public void createEvent(String title, String location, String description, String startDate, String endDate)
{

    Calendar calendarStart = CalendarPlugin.getCalendarFromISO(startDate);
    Calendar calendarEnd = CalendarPlugin.getCalendarFromISO(endDate);


    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1"));
     try {

      ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

      values.put(Events.DTSTART, calendarStart.getTimeInMillis());
      values.put(Events.DTEND, calendarEnd.getTimeInMillis());
      values.put(Events.TITLE, title);
      values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
      values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1 );
      values.put("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");          // values.put(Events._ID, meeting_id);
      values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

      Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
      eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        Toast toast =Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Calender Event Added" + eventID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

     } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Ru able to see the events ?

Comment: Yes, I can see the events as well as I receive notifications for these events. You need to sync your calendar on the device.